# What is "Godspeed"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, etymology

Title says it all.  What does it really mean?  What is its origin?

Comment: [godspeed](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=godspeed) from etymonline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase ***Godspeed (you)"*** is akin to ***good luck*** in meaning.

Except that ***Godspeed!*** is meant for wishing a

> "prosperous journey"

From: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/godspeed)

Origin:

> Middle English god speid, from the phrase God spede you God prosper you
>
> First Known Use: 15th century

-EDIT-

From : [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Godspeed)

> From Middle English phrase God spede (“may God cause you to succeed”), from God (“god”) + spede, subjunctive of speden (“to prosper”), from Old English spēdan, from spēd (“success”) (see speed).